# email validation for dot in the beginning of host name and 2 dots in the middle of host name

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble adding another filter to my email validator expression:
Here it is:

```
var fullEmailCheck = "((?=(^\..{1,64}@.{1,255}))([!#$%&'*+\\-\\/=?\\^_`{|}~a-zA-Z0-9}]{1,64}(\\.[!#$%&'*+\\-\\/=?\\^_`{|}~a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}){0,})@((\\[(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\\])|([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}){1,})))";
```

I want to add a check for:

1. dot in the beginning of host name.
2. a check for 2 consecutive dots in the middle of host name.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your regex already does not allow for a dot directly at the beginning of the hostname.

Comment: It doesn't allow either two dots that follow each other. So you already have what you want.

Comment: Or do you want to **allow** those dots, knowing that such addresses are invalid.

Comment: It's strange because when I'm testing it in JS I get an that the email with the dot in the beginning and the two dots in the middle are are ok.

Answer (score 0):

`((\\[(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\\])|([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}){1,})))`

means: either

- `(\\[(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\\])` what is an IP address
- `([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}){1,}))` is a host name. It is clear that it cannot begin with a dot or contain two dots following each other.

The problem with the validation must be elsewhere. The regular expression is not applied correctly or the result is not checked correcly.